# Regex Pattern to validate Numerical Value

Tags: java, regex

I need to validate the following string to match only if the **Number** is **greater** than **0**.

> [D:\ifs\Pearl_Sync_Test\Client\Pub\Checkout\crm\source\crm\client\Ifs.SM.Common.MSOffice\Ifs.SM.Common.MSOffice.csproj]
>
> ```
> 47 Warning(s)
> 5 Error(s)
> ```

My solution so far is to match the above string

```
((\d)\sError\(s\))
```

Resulting in extracting this string, **5 Error(s)**

So, is it possible to check if the Number is greater than 0 ?

Thanks

Comment: No it is not, this is just the part I wanted. I've updated the content

Comment: A bit unclear: Do you want to know a second regexp, in addition to yours, in order to find whether the number you extracted is greater than zero? Or do you want a regexp that *improves* yours, and  will not match it at all if it is zero? And do you want to match the "Warnings" as well?

Comment: I just want to match 5 Error(s), and yes I need to improve my current Pattern. Not a second regex pattern. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following regular expression idiom for error numbers that start with a digit `> 1`:

```
String[] errors = {"5 Error(s)", "50 Error(s)", "0 Error(s)"};
//                           | starts with digit > 0
//                           |    | optionally ends with 0 or more digits
//                           |    |    | rest of the pattern
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[1-9]\\d* Error\\(s\\)");
for (String s: errors) {
    System.out.println(s.matches(p.pattern()));
}
```

**Output**

```
true
true
false
```

Comment: `+` not really needed

Comment: Not that it really matters here, but `[1-9]\\d*` does the job too, and it's less catastrophic than `[1-9]+\\d*`.

Comment: @Rawing true, thanks for noticing. Although I fail to understand why "catastrophic"!

Comment: Because it can match strings like ` Error(s)`

Comment: @Mena: Reference to [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).

Answer (score 4):

Regular expressions are not really fit for this problem but assuming you will not get negative errors, you can just check if it's not 0.

```
"[1-9]\\d*\\sError\\(s\\)"
```

[Demo](http://fiddle.re/4zwcy6)

Comment: The answer you accepted was posted after mine, but anyway, glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 0):

[1-9][0-9]*\sError(s)?

thanks rawling.

Comment: The question mark does __not__ make the second digit optional. It makes the `+` quantifier non-greedy. This won't match single digit numbers.

Answer (score -1):

in this case wouldn't you want to strip the errors bit off and check the value after you cast the first part to an int?
It seems like you're trying to do string validation while you actually want to know what a certain number is.